# AspNetBoilerplate - Server-side JavaScript code injection

Tags: cookies, aspnetboilerplate, x-xsrf-token

Our company had a security scan done on our software that is running AspNetBoilerplate (Abp 2.0.2.0) and AspNet Zero as the framework.

The scan found three occurrences of Server-side JavaScript code injection in cookies (RequestVerificationToken, XSRF-TOKEN, AspNet.ApplicationCookie).

I was wondering how I can investigate further and remediate when it is in the framework?

Has anyone else had a security scan done and encountered these and,  if so, are they false positives?

Comment: That's (1) at best, vague — how is it injected, (2) not ABP-specific cookies, and (3) a 1.5-year outdated version of the framework and base solution.

Comment: a google search on `XSRF-TOKEN` will give you ammo to show it is a measure that `prevents` xss.